# Where is HttpClient and related classes in SPFx 1.1?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I am finally able to get started using SPFx.  Stuck on 2016 / SPFx 1.1.

The [documentation for the `HttpClient` class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-http/httpclient?view=sp-typescript-latest) says it's in the `@microsoft/sp-http` package.  However, the Yeoman generator did not include that package when I scaffolded out a new 2016/1.1 project.

I can get to `IWebPartContext` in `@microsoft/sp-webpart-base`, and pass a context object from the outer web part into a component.  And the context object has a `httpClient` property.  However, to make web requests, I gather that I will need to use some other classes (notably `HttpClientResponse` if I want to get anything back from the server).

Where are those classes, if not in `@microsoft/sp-http`?  I am assuming the generator did not include a dependency to that package because that package is not compatible with v1.1?  Or do I need to just add it myself?

Here are the packages the Yeoman generator added by default:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core": "~1.4.0-0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base": "~1.1.0",
    "@types/es6-promise": "0.0.33",
    "@types/react": "0.14.46",
    "@types/react-addons-shallow-compare": "0.14.17",
    "@types/react-addons-test-utils": "0.14.15",
    "@types/react-addons-update": "0.14.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "0.14.18",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.1",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "0.14.46"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.1.0",
    "@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.1.0",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.38",
    "ajv": "~5.2.2",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1"
  }
```

Comment: It is there present as a dependency. So, wont be present in the `package.json` file.
Just add this statement : 
`import { HttpClient, HttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http";` in your webpart and it will work

Comment: That is aggravatingly confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `@microsoft/sp-http` package is available for use in SP 2016. But it is in the form of an upstream dependency, so it is not visible in the `package.json` file.

Yes, it quite confusing, but unfortunately that's the way it works :(

To use it, you can add the below import statement in your code and consume it in your methods:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http"
```

If you are working with SharePoint REST APIs, then would suggest that you use `SPHttpClient`. The `HttpClient` is primarily for consuming APIs outside of SharePoint.